# TinyMCE 6 and winform Webbrower control

Tags: hosted, tinymce-6

I currently use a TinyMCE 3 in hosted mode in my application in an embedded windows form webcontrol object.
It has been working fine for many years.

I need to migrate to the lastest TinyMCE 6 because the version 3 obviously doesn't accept media tags of HTML 5

But i can't succeed in make work TinyMCE 6 in the same conditions in hosted mode in an embedded windows form webcontrol object.

Anyone has already succeed using TinyMCE 6 with winform webbrowser control ?

Thanks for your help